Find all elements of a permutation group that have a specific order in GAP
Basically the title.
Filtered(ConjugacyClasses(G), c -> Order(Representative(c)) = order);

works but in my case G (the Rubik's cube group and various subgroups of it) is so large that this computation takes over half an hour. It's very clearly overkill given that I only care about a subset of these conjugacy classes. I know GAP provides a ConjugacyClass(G, g) function but that finds the class of a specific element, whereas I'm looking for the classes of element that satisfy the arbitrary order condition as stated earlier. If it helps, it appears that the source code for ConjugacyClass is here.

I thought an update would be appreciated. I modified the source of ConjugacyClassesViaRadical to remove unwanted centralizer calculations to achieve a 5x speedup from 35 minutes to 6.5 minutes. However this is still slow; further help is welcome.
